# How to pick the file extension for a new file format

Tags: file, operating-system, software-distribution

I'm writing a new compiler that will produce a result file, and I'd like to assign it the ".sys" extension.

Now here's the problem: [.sys is already in use within the dregs of Windows and DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sys).

**Is there a really good reason to hunt down a unique file extension for every new file format?**

I'm trending towards using .sys because:

1) Windows .sys files are a very specific use and very few programmers deal with them

2) The problem domain of my compiler is very far removed from anything a Windows .sys file does

Its hard for me to immagine both .sys files existing and people having ambiguous conversations about their ".sys" files--so I'm left grasping for reasons (maybe technical?) not to go ahead and use .sys.

Comment: On DOS/Windows systems, .sys files are typically some sort of system device driver. It's pretty standard to see them that way, as it is to see .exe or .com files as executables. Probably not a good choice - are you really writing **sys**tem files? How do you know whether it's your file or a different type altogether? How does a user when setting up a backup group?

Comment: There are only 17576 three letter acronyms; if you need your extension to be relatively unique and pertinent to your usage, I'd probably suggest using more letters...  Says the guy who's taking a break from debugging a program he's currently futzing with that's generating a new file format, and he's given it a TLA extension.  Admittedly, my TLA has a z in it, so there's not so much competition there... except in the problem domain for the program I'm futzing with.  If you're doing this in Windows, I'd very strongly recommend against using .sys due to Windows program/extension associations.